# Write a function as $\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} a_n x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

We have $f(x) = (x+ x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^4$.

Now I want to write this as $\sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} a_n x^n$.

What I got:

$f(x) = (x+ x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^4 = x^4 (1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^4$

We know: $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty} x^n$.

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{d^3}{dx^3} (\frac{1}{1-x})= \frac{6}{(1-x)^4}$.

Then $\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = \frac{1}{6} \sum n (n-1) (n-2) x^{n-3}$, what gives

$x^4 \frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = \frac{1}{6} \sum n (n-1) (n-2) x^{n+1} = \frac{1}{6} \sum  (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) x^{n}$

If I look now on Wolfram Alpha at the expanded form, this expression is only correct for $4 \leq n \leq 9$. For $n \geq 10$ it gives other values of the coefficients. What goes wrong?

Comment: Note that you don't have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$; you have $\sum_{n=0}^5 x^n$.  So you must start with $(1-x^6)/(1-x)$, not $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: I didn't read what you did. The function is a polynomial, the Maclaurin series is the polynomial.

Comment: @Brian: How should I work out $(1-x^6)/(1-x)$ in this case? I finally want to have a series that represents $x^4 + 4 x^5 + 10 x^6+...$ as on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @clubkli: Unfortunately, instead of $x^4/(1-x)^4$, you have $x^4(1-x^6)^4/(1-x)^4$.  You will have to expand that, if you want to go down this route, I think.  If you let $g(x) = x^4/(1-x)^4 = (1/6)\sum (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)x^n$, what you want is $(1-4x^6+6x^{12}-4x^{18}+x^{24})g(x)$.

Comment: It is fairly easy to derive an expression for $a_n$, but evaluating it (for all $24$ values) seems tedious: $a_n = \sum_{p+6k+4 = n}{4\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{(p+3)(p+2)(p+1)}{6}$ for $n\leq 24$ and $a_n = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Winther: If I want to compute for example $a_{17}$, how are $k$ and $p$ determinated?

Comment: @Winther: And how did you derived this expression for $a_n$?

Comment: The sum is over all $k,p$ with $0\leq k \leq 4$ and $0\leq p$ such that $p+6k+4 = n$. For $n\leq 9$ the sum has only one term $k=0,p=n-4$ so $a_n = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}$.

Comment: Binomial theorem $(1-x^6)^4 = \sum_{k=0}^4{4\choose k}(-1)^kx^{6k}$ together with $\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(p+3)(p+2)(p+1)}{6} x^{p} $ gives $f(x) = \frac{x^4(1-x^6)^4}{ (1-x)^4}= \sum_{p=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^4{4\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{(p+3)(p+2)(p+1)}{6} x^{p+6k+4}$. Since $f$ is of degree $24$ we have $a_n = 0$ for all $n>24$.

Comment: @Winther: Thank you, your answer is for me the most useful. The difficulty for me was the power series for $(1-x^6)^4$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$x+x^2+\cdots+x^6=\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}$$ and then we can expand the numerator with a binomial expansion:

$$(x+x^2+\cdots+x^6)^4 = \frac{(x-x^7)^4}{(1-x)^4} = (1-x)^{-4} \sum_{k=0}^4 {4 \choose k} (-1)^k x^{6k+4}$$

$$=\left( \frac16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+3)(n+2)(n+1) x^{n} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^4 {4 \choose n} (-1)^n x^{6n+4} \right)$$

$$=\left( \frac16 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+3)(n+2)(n+1) x^{n} \right) \left( x^{4} - 4 x^{10} + 24 x^{16} - 4 x^{22} + x^{28}\right).$$

We can call $(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=b_n$, for the sake of brevity.

$$=\frac16 \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^{n+4} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4b_n x^{n+10} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 24 b_nx^{n+16} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4b_n x^{n+22} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^{n+28}\right)$$

$$= \frac16 \left( \sum_{n=4}^\infty b_{n-4} x^{n} - \sum_{n=10}^\infty 4b_{n-10} x^{n} + \sum_{n=16}^\infty 24 b_{n-16}x^{n} - \sum_{n=22}^\infty 4b_{n-22} x^{n} + \sum_{n=28}^\infty b_{n-28} x^{n}\right)$$

Finally we have $$\frac16
\left(\sum_{n=4}^{9} (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) x^n +\sum_{n=10}^{15} \left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9)\right] x^n + \sum_{n=16}^{21} \left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9) + 24(n-13)(n-14)(n-15)\right]x^n +
\sum_{n=22}^{27} \left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) -  4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9) + 24(n-13)(n-14)(n-15)-4(n-19)(n-20)(n-21)\right]x^n
+\sum_{n=28}^{\infty} \left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9) + 24(n-13)(n-14)(n-15)-4(n-19)(n-20)(n-21) + (n-25)(n-26)(n-27)\right]x^n\right).$$

However, we know that the resulting polynomial has a degree of $24$, thus all of the coefficients for the last series must be zero, and the coefficients of $x^{25}$, $x^{26}$ and $x^{27}$ are zero. This can be verified by expanding the polynomials in $n$. Thus:

$$
\sum_{n=4}^{9} \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6} x^n + \sum_{n=10}^{15} \frac{\left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9)\right]}{6} x^n + \sum_{n=16}^{21} \frac{\left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9) + 24(n-13)(n-14)(n-15)\right]}{6}x^n + \sum_{n=22}^{24} \frac{\left[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) - 4 (n-7)(n-8)(n-9) + 24(n-13)(n-14)(n-15)-4(n-19)(n-20)(n-21)\right]}{6} x^n$$

Answer (score 0):

(can't leave a comment)

You'll want the [multinomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialSeries.html) formula for this purpose:

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k a_j\right)^n=\sum_{\stackrel{n_j \geq 0}{\sum_{j=1}^k n_j=n}}\frac{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^k n_j!}\prod_{j=1}^k a_j^{n_j}$$

where the condition on the sum on the right means to sum all over the [integer partitions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html) of the power $n$.

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing up finite sums with infinite sums.

Another problem is that anything calcualted using an infinite sum is likely to have limited validity. Why add that constraint to your solution?

You have that $f(x) = x^4 (1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^4$

Why not just expand that bracket?

$(1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^2$

$=1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5$

$..... + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 +x^6$

$.........+x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 +x^6+x^7$

$..............+x^3 + x^4 + x^5 +x^6+x^7+x^8$

$...................+x^4 + x^5 +x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9$

$........................+x^5 +x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}$

$=1+ 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5 +5x^6+4x^7+3x^8+2x^9+x^{10}$

Then find $\left( 1+ 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5 +5x^6+4x^7+3x^8+2x^9+x^{10}\right)^2$

$= 1+ 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5 +5x^6+4x^7+3x^8+2x^9+x^{10}$

$..... + 2x + 4x^2 + 6x^3 + 8x^4 + 10x^5 +12x^6+10x^7+8x^8+6x^9+4x^{10}+2x^{12}$

Coefficients are:

```
 1                                    =  1
 2+  2                                =  4
 3+  4+  3                            = 10
 4+  6+  6+  4                        = 20
 5+  8+  9+  8+ 5                     = 35
 6+ 10+ 12+ 12+ 10+  6                = 56
 5+ 12+ 15+ 16+ 15+ 12+  7            = 82
 4+ 10+ 18+ 20+ 20+ 18+ 14+  8        =112
 3+  8+ 15+ 24+ 25+ 24+ 21+ 16+  9    =145
 2+  6+ 12+ 20+ 30+ 30+ 28+ 24+ 18+ 10=180
 1+  4+  9+ 16+ 25+ 36+ 35+ 32+ 27+ 20=205
     2+  6+ 12+ 20+ 30+ 42+ 40+ 26+ 30=218
                                      =218
                                      =204
                                      =175
                                      =130
                                      = 90
                                      = 56
                                      = 29
                                      = 10
```

Comment: Expand the brackets would give a totally chaos. The first square that you have worked out is still clear. But the last expression with 10 terms would not be clear I guess. I thought there must be a way that is more clear.

Comment: @clubkli Manually expanding would be a mess, but we have this nice thing called the multinomial theorem to do it for us.

Comment: I think it's still quite straightforward - will demonstrate.

Comment: You're squaring the wrong polynomial in your box, aren't you?  None of the coefficients are greater than $6$.  So the $x^6$ term will have coefficient $80$, not $84$, for instance.

Comment: Oh yes - got carried away

Comment: All terms after $56$ are wrong ($80,104,125,140,125,\ldots$ where the rest of the terms are mirrored about the $140$)

Answer (score -1):

We know that for any Taylor series representation:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ f^{(n)}(a) } {n!} (x-a)^n $$

It looks like you want the series centered at a=0.

So to get the coefficient for terms 1,2,3,4,.... evaluate:
$$b_n=\frac{ f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$